# Solr indexing CSV containing Doublequotes

Tags: csv, solr, escaping

Im trying to index a CSV which has the following line using Solr 3.6 and curl

ex:  "123","456","789",""""145","132"

So the data itself is """145

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solr/coll11/update/csv -F "stream.file=D:\NewTesting\LuceneTest.csv" -F  "commit=true" -F "keepEmpty=true" -F "encapsulate=""
```

All im getting is a cant read line error i have even tried using escape ="

P.S I cant edit the data as it comes from the client and is huge and the client wants it to be how it is

Answer (score 1):

The UpdateCSV documentation on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV#encapsulator) states that you should escape the **encapsulator**-character by doubling it.

So, the data you send to Solr should look as follows:

```
"123","456","789","""""""145","132"
```

Comment: The default is encapsulator="

Comment: Yes, which is why I'm suggesting it is escaped by doubling, as described in the linked documentation?

Comment: @JoelWestberg hey i cannot change the data it is really huge it might contain thousands of records in the same way i cant go editing everything and the client wants the data to be how it is the actual csv file is 10gb of size with some 24 million records

Comment: Their data is not a correctly formatted CSV file. The Solr CSV Update handler can't handle your broken CSV. You'll either need to convert the data file, or read it in through an application where you can do the splitting of fields yourself according to your logic.